# Is there an even slimmer ReaderWriterLockSlim available for .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, performance, locking

I have a scenario where the implementation of ReaderWriterLockSlim takes up a significant proportion of the CPU time. Some of the features of ReaderWriterLockSlim (like lock upgrading, and probably re-entrancy) are not required, which lends me to believe that gains can be had by using an even slimmer implementation.

My first go would just be to start from the .net core source and strip out all the stuff I don't need from ReaderWriterLockSlim, but if there is a simpler but robust 'ReaderWriterLockSlimmer' out there, trying those out would be preferred.

Premature optimization comments are not welcome.

Comment: If it's taking up a lot of CPU then it just means you've got a lot of contention and so you're spending a lot of time waiting on the lock.  Changing the lock's code isn't going to lower the contention.

Comment: At the moment, the answer to the question is almost certainly "no". Perhaps a higher level description of the problem might allow someone to suggest a different approach?

Comment: @Servy No, there is not a lot of contention. In my problem domain, I often have to worry about microseconds.

Comment: @spender I'm not sure why you say that the answer is 'almost certainly "no"'. I'm sure without a doubt that one can make a faster implementation of ReaderWriterLockSlim by removing features. I'm also sure that I'm not the only one with this need. The framework developers make choices that are 'reasonable for broad use cases', but sometimes one can get better results with specialization.

Comment: @spender To add to that, here's an example of someone writing their own lock. They had a different set of needs than mine though, so their implementation does include read->write upgrading for example. http://www.adammil.net/blog/v111_Creating_High-Performance_Locks_and_Lock-free_Code_for_NET_.html

Comment: I agree that more info won't hurt. For example, article you link implement what looks like general purpose readwrite lock, but you are saying you have different set of needs, so what are those needs?

Comment: ReaderWriterLockSlim scales poorly before .net core 2.1, because of the unreasonable amount of spinning done (which eats a lot of CPU). The amount of spinning is proportional to the number of CPU cores you have on your computer, so it becomes even more of a problem on modern hardware (in my company we use servers with 32 cores, many .net synchronization primitives are completely unusable because of the spinning issue). Is upgrading to .net core 2.1 an option for you?

Comment: @KevinGosse Interesting. We're presently on .Net Framework 4.7.1 Are the improvements you mention making it over to .Net Framework? What version?

Comment: @Evk I thought specifying what we don't need (eg: we don't need upgrading, we don't need multiple writers, and we don't need recursion) would be enough to point to something better. But, we can go into more detail if it is helpful. There are somewhere on the order of 50k-350k RW locks which are acquired 60+ times per second for read-only access. Sometimes there are multiple readers. Infrequently (every few seconds), one writer batch updates a bunch of these structures. The structures are too large for a copy-on-update approach.

Comment: @KevinGosse I think the changes you are referring to are here: https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet-framework-early-access/blob/master/release-notes/build-3052/dotnet-build-3052-changes.md "ReaderWriterLockSlim now scales better under contention." I think that the fact that contention is unusual in my case may imply that I won't see benefit from this, but I'll check .Net Framework 4.7.2 nontheless.

Comment: @ZacharyBurns Those changes are only part of the story, there's also this: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/13556   Unfortunately I don't know if this one has been ported to .net framework yet